# Size modifier commands and wrapfig

Tags: fontsize, wrapfigure, wrap

I'm writing my curriculum using the `moderncv` class and banking style. I'd like to add a small image with the text wrapping around it. 
To pack everything I'm using the `\small{}` environment along with `wrapfigure`, but the text actually covers the figure without wrapping around it. I have no such a problem without using `\small{}`.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{R}{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{-25pt}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{me}
\end{wrapfigure}
\vspace{-20pt}
\small{Rather long text which covers my image.}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not start the paragraph after wrapfig in a new group that ends before the paragraph ends. So remove the `{}` around `{Rather long text which covers my image.}`  which are just generating a spurious group (they are not delimiting an argument to `\small` as size commands do not take an argument.

Comment: That is not really a good solution, as it has the effect that all the following text is also small, but I just want it to be small for this single section or paragraph.

Comment: @Albert I do not understand your comment at all. The usage of `\small` in the question is wrong and will affect the rest of the document as I comment here.   so you can delimit the size change with surrounding group or simply put `\normalsize` before the next paragraph.

Comment: What I mean is, that directly using `\small` is not a good solution, as there is no easy way to reset the previous font size after the paragraph. You could explicitly put `\normalsize` after it, but that is only correct if `\normalsize` is the correct font size, and breaks once you have a different default font size. I think having the `wrapfig` and the `\small` together in an own group would be a much cleaner solution. But then the question is still, how would that work. All I tried so far does not work correctly.

Comment: @Albert as I say you can use `\normalsize` after the paragraph or put `{` before the `wrapfig` and  a blank line and `}` after the paragraph. That is just standard latex markup, not really related to `wrapfig` at all. You should never have a default size that is different to `\normalsize` that size should be defined to be the document default, but you can use grouping to automatically restore the previous font)

Comment: Ok, so a construct like `\small .... \wrapfig ... \normalsize` is the correct way to do it? This was not clear to me. I thought it's better to use `\begin{...} ... \wrapfig ... \end{...}` or `{ ... \wrapfig ... }`. I tried that (using `{...}`) but that did not correctly work together with wrapfig.

Comment: @Albert the site doesn't really work by asking comments on old questions, if you have a question it is better to post a new question. As I say you can use `{ ... \small ...}` and have the font size restore to what it was. If it doesn't work for you you are doing something wrong, but unless you post a question with a test document I can not guess what.

Comment: Well, the question is exactly like already asked exactly here. People on SE would surely mark it as duplicate. I'm just wondering if your answer is not optimal, as I explained in my comments.